# ID is being applied to the a element generated by React Bootstrap, not the encompassing div

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, react-bootstrap

So, previously I was using the 'ml-auto' class for my navbar, for my dropdown to push itself all the way over to the left. However, I don't want it to push itself all the way to the left when it goes into a small screen, and the navbar changes into a vertical orientation.

I tried giving my NavDropdown the following class and ID:

```
className={styles.naviDropdown}
id='navigationDropdown'
```

and apply the following style to it

```
.naviDropdown#navigationDropdown {
    margin-left: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .naviDropdown#navigationDropdown {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

So, this seems like it would work perfectly well, but unfortunately, it does not. Doing this makes the website completely disregard any of the CSS, and makes my navbar look all wacky and evenly spaced, as opposed to justifying my links left, and navbar right.

I've found out, through the inspector, that for some reason, the id is being applied to the a element generated by React Bootstrap, not the encompassing div, which is given the proper class.

[image]

Any ideas what might be going on?

Any help would be much appreciated, and let me know if I need to provide more info!

Edit:
I tried reformatting my code in the ways specified within this [Github discussion](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/208#issuecomment-278844673), and unfortunately, my issue still remains the same--the ID is assigned to the 'a' element, rather than the dropdown div.

Comment: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/issues/208#issuecomment-278844673

Comment: @brc-dd Just gave that a try! I tried changing my code to match both of those methods and unfortunately, i'm still experiencing the same issue. Perhaps it's an issue with the React-Bootstrap library?

Comment: Please show more of your code. It's not apparent why the class is being applied to a container element. Also, the class portion of an selector including an ID is pointless. IDs must be unique anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all i needed to do was surround the dropdown element with a 'div' element and then apply the id to that. There might be some deeper issue at play here, but this fixed my issue.